issue in barryvdh/laravel-dompdf while generation PDF

I am getting following error while generating pdf in barryvdh/laravel-dompdf.

Dompdf\Options::validateArtifactPath(): Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/exhibition/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Options.php on line 1073
This error is popping up while generating PDF.

Hi, you need to use :
$pdf->download('invoice');

Hi @ZbobModel.php, This solution is not working

please use var_dump() or dd() to inspect the value of the path variable (the pdf) to see what you get?

Please don't post images of code or errors!

I just encountered this issue as well.
When Dompdf\Dompdf is constructed it, in turn, constructs an instance of Dompdf\Options. This fails in Dompdf\Options::setLogOutputFile when the config key dompdf.options.log_output_file is set to null (which it was, for me). Apparently, this option must now be a string.
I set this config key to storage_path('dompdf.log') and this resolved the issue.
